# Break array of words in chunks based on the maximum number of character

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, cpu-word

I need to break the array of words into chunks based on maximum number of character:

```js
const maxChar = 50
const arrOfWords =['Emma','Woodhouse,','handsome,','clever,','and','rich,','with','a','comfortable','home','and','happy','disposition,','seemed','to','unite','some','of','the','best','blessings','of','existence;','and','had','lived','nearly','twenty-one','years','in','the','world','with','very','little','to','distress','or','vex','her.']
```

The desire result is to count the char of each word and break the array when the count of char reach maxChar.

```
const resultArr = [['Emma','Woodhouse,','handsome,','clever,','and','rich,','with','a'],['comfortable','home','and',..]....]
```

The problem is that I am using 2 for loops and want to know if there is a better way to reach the same result

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: And what is your code so far in trying this? How have you approached it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Ohh sorry I forgot to mention the fail, the problem is that I am using 2 for loops and want to know if there is a better way to reach the same approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array.reduce function to loop over and create your new array.

I am assuming that if the new word would take the length over the limit it is just moved to the next array (not split partway through the word)

```js
const maxChar = 50
const arrOfWords = ['Emma', 'Woodhouse,', 'handsome,', 'clever,', 'and', 'rich,', 'with', 'a', 'comfortable', 'home', 'and', 'happy', 'disposition,', 'seemed', 'to', 'unite', 'some', 'of', 'the', 'best', 'blessings', 'of', 'existence;', 'and', 'had', 'lived', 'nearly', 'twenty-one', 'years', 'in', 'the', 'world', 'with', 'very', 'little', 'to', 'distress', 'or', 'vex', 'her.']

let lengthSoFar = 0

const results = arrOfWords.reduce((accumulator, word) => {
  const lastAddedResult = accumulator.pop() || []

  if (lengthSoFar + word.length < maxChar) {
    lengthSoFar += word.length
    lastAddedResult.push(word)
    accumulator.push(lastAddedResult)
  } else {
    lengthSoFar = word.length
    accumulator.push(lastAddedResult)
    accumulator.push([word])
  }
  return accumulator
}, [])

console.log(...results)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one better way:

```js
const arrOfWords = ['Emma', 'Woodhouse,', 'handsome,', 'clever,', 'and', 'rich,', 'with', 'a', 'comfortable', 'home', 'and', 'happy', 'disposition,', 'seemed', 'to', 'unite', 'some', 'of', 'the', 'best', 'blessings', 'of', 'existence;', 'and', 'had', 'lived', 'nearly', 'twenty-one', 'years', 'in', 'the', 'world', 'with', 'very', 'little', 'to', 'distress', 'or', 'vex', 'her.']

const result = arrOfWords.join(' ').match(/.{1,50}\W/g).map(line => line.split(" ").filter(word => word.length > 0)) // 50 is the num of chars
 
 console.log('result: ', result)
```